# python list of lists to np.array() return ndarray of list

Tags: python

I have a list of lists of int: list1. When I convert it to 2d np.array(), it seems like sometime it returns a 2d numpy.ndarray and sometime it returns a 1d numpy.ndarray of list.
what am I missing here?

Comment: Examples of whenever it does either?

Comment: dtype=object if it can't convert every element to int.

Comment: because not all lists of lists can be converted to a multidimensional array. Consider, `[[1,2,3], [1,2], [1,2,3]]`. What would the *shape* of the resulting `numpy.ndarray` be? A numpy array must have fixed-size dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

use

```py
new_array = np.array(your_list, dtype=float)
```

so that it will correctly convert all element to floats, and the final result will be a 2D array.

if your list of list have unequal lengths or not castable to float this will raise a ValueError.

Comment: This doesn't fix it per se, though it may raise an error that helps find the problem.

Comment: @MateenUlhaq you're right, i'll add that.